# Can you go back a step in a waterfall dialog if the user entered wrong data? #botframework

Tags: bots, waterfall, botframework

In a dialog, I want to ask the user for his email address.
If the user entered an invalid email by mistake, I would like to be able to go back or get into some "loop" situation of keep asking him for his email until he enters a valid one.
What's the best way to accomplish that?
I couldn't find any way to go back a step in a waterfall dialog.

Answer (score 4):

You can by calling `next({ resumed: builder.ResumeReason.back })` but there's actually a better way to do what you're trying to do.

In the latest v0.8.0 version of the library I added a new `DialogAction.validatedPrompt()` action that lets you create a new prompt with a custom validation routine. With that you can call your '/emailPrompt' dialog instead of Prompts.text() and you won't need to go backwards.  Check out the basics-validatedPrompt example to see it in action.

Comment: as per libray version 3.8, `validatedPrompt()` has been deprecated and you should use `session.replaceDialog('dialogName', { reprompt: true });` instead. Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-replace) for reference.